# Read a document from a file path on a Mac computer

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have a working VBA Word macro that I run on a windows computer. This macro reads a document based on a file path. The path is not recognized when I try to run the macro on a Mac computer. What is the correct way to declare the file path for Word running on a Mac?  My macro reads a file that contains a table. I have a loop to copy each cell as a variable to run a process. The loop works and is not shown below because the issue is that the macro does not recognize the file path and the document with the table on a Mac computer.

```
Dim Variable As String          'Each cell value is copied one by one into a variable
Dim FileFullPath As String      'File path for document
Dim FileDoc As Word.Document    'Word document that contains a table
Dim Row_Counter As Integer      'Row counter for word table
Dim Col_Counter As Integer      'Column counter for word table

FileFullPath = "C:\folder\file_document.docx"  
Set FileDoc = Documents.Open(FileFullPath)
Variable = FileDoc.Tables(1).Rows(Row_Counter).Cells(Col_Counter).range.Text
```

Note: Using Documents(1) or (2) doesn't work in this case, because my process involves going back and forth between files and I cannot control which document is opened first or last by the user. Thank you

Comment: I found this advice on a similar topic `If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then FileFullPath = Replace(FileFullPath, "\", ":")`

Comment: What do you mean by `Documents(1) or (2)`? If the files are not open, the Documents collection wont have anything in (1) or (2) anyway. If the files are already open, then you just need to check everything in `Documents` for  `Document.Name` and find the correct one.

Comment: `C:\folder\file_document.docx` is not a valid macOS path, not just because the delimiters are wrong, but also because there's nothing like drive letters on macOS. What's the actual path the file will be at on a macOS system?

Comment: @Toddleson, Since I don't have a Mac, I cannot test if this path works: 'If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then FileFullPath= folder:file_document.docx'   I will find a Mac user that I can test this with. Using Documents(1) or (2) is my next potential solution but that will change my code since I constantly extract information from one file to the next and will have to validate which one is Documents(1) or (2) based on the name. Thank you

Comment: @toddleson Based on your suggestion, I have modified my code to use ActiveDocument and Documents() and the code works.

Comment: With ActiveDocument
  Filetovalidate = ActiveDocument.Name
  Documents(Filetovalidate).Activate
End With

Comment: @toddleson I also added a loop to identify the document(i) i value.  With Activedocuments and Documents() I don't need to have a file path and therefore the macro works for Mac computers as well as PCs.                                                            '''For i = 1 To Word.Application.Documents.Count
  If Documents(i).Name = "filename.docx" Then
     FileDocumentsNum = i
  End If
Next i '''

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was talking about. You can find it in `Documents` using `.Name`. Exactly like that. But instead of saving `i`. Why not just save the Document Object? `If Documents(i).Name = "filename.docx" Then Set MyDoc = Documents(i)` and now you have `MyDoc` as a saved variable, no need to use `ActiveDocument` or `Documents(i)` anymore.